# Julia - Is this really a Singleton Anonymous Function?

Tags: optimization, julia

```
using FastAnonymous

# By making this a generated function we should get only one instance 
# for a given type (singleton for each Value type)

@generated function save2arr_gen{Value}(::Type{Value})

    array = zeros(Value, 100)

    return @anon (t, v) -> begin
        array[t] = v
    end
end
```

`@code_native test()` indicates it is, but is it?

```
function test()
    save2arr = save2arr_gen(Float64)
    save2arr(1, 24.24)

    shouldAlsoBe_save2arr = save2arr_gen(Float64)
    shouldAlsoBe_save2arr(1, 100.0)

    @assert save2arr.array[1] == 100.0 # This checks out.
end
```

Which should mean that no matter how many times `save2arr_gen(Float64)` is called only a single value (a lambda function) has been generated for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this paragraph from [J_Doc](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#generated-functions):

> The body of the generated function is only executed once (not entirely
>   true, see note below) when the method for that specific set of
>   argument types is compiled. After that, the expression returned from
>   the generated function on the first invocation is re-used as the
>   method body.

So in the sample above, `array = zeros(Value, 100)` only **executed once** per each value of `Value`, And after that each call to `save2arr_gen` will result a new mutation expression, for a same `array`.